# Words in <option> tag exceeds at iphone 4,4s Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, css

I am doing my web application in iphone 4s. Once the content in html `<select>` `<option>` tag goes too long.

When the select tag was clicked, the Safari browser renders the exceeded parts in `<option>` tag as '...'.

The exceeded content must be displayed for the customer. So how to deal with the problem.

I tried to set the style **font-size** in select tag as `<select style='font-size:12px'>`, it could only change the `<select>` tag but not the `<option>`.

Comment: You can't make the `<select>` wider?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone, but the desktop Safari does respond to setting a font size on the option. Can you show more of the HTML and the CSS? Maybe you have a simple typo.